# Qemu/kvm (virt-manager) very slow after update - AMD Ryzen

Tags: virtual-machine, kvm, qemu, manjaro, virt-manager

I am using an up-to-date version of manjaro mate and have virt-manager 3.2.0-1 installed on my Thinkpad E14 (AMD Ryzen 5 4500U). Using either GNOME Boxes or virt-manager it is really slow:

[image]

It really bothers me because I know it just work flawlessly in the past. Unfortunately I don’t know what update caused this issue. I did a reinstall but the issue still persists. I tried using Ubuntu MATE but it is also very slow there. I used quickemu as well and it just worked perfect back then, currently installation fails.

I do not know whether [this issue](https://github.com/wimpysworld/quickemu/issues/50) has something to do with this one. But there I got a error

```
/usr/share/libdrm/amdgpu.ids: No such file or directory
```

and actually amdgpu.ids is located in/var/lib/mhwd/ids/pci/amdgpu.ids.

I know the data availability is not great but maybe someone with AMD Ryzen experiences similar issues that can be resolved.

I tried using virtualbox and there are no performance issues, however I really prefer using GNOME Boxes or virt-manager.

Thanks for any ideas!

Comment: Please show qemu cmdline as it is visible in `ps -axo args | grep '[q]emu'`.

Comment: this commando shows nothing :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I changed the video settings to **Virtio** and now it's running pretty decent!

Answer (score 2):

I was wrong to say the code to mitigate spectre/meltdown was the reason for the low performance. Turns out `virt-manager` was locked to one core which I fixed it by changing `Whonix-Workstation*.xml` at line 12 (approx) remove `cpuset =1` and between opening and closing brackets of `vcpu` define the amount of cores Eg.4 . Then applying the changes using

```
sudo virsh -c qemu:///system define Whonix-Workstation*.xml
```

In my case I had 8 logical cores I assigned half to the Gateway and half to workstation so they don't overlap.

Answer (score 1):

It's slow even for me. It's because they included code to mitigate spectre and meltdown attacks on the hypervisor.

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thank you for your contribution. Perhaps you could add some links to references for the statements you made?

Comment: But why is virtualbox then fine?